# Google Developer Console API

Tags: google-api, google-developer-tools

Google have for almost every service an API, but I can't find any API for the Google Developer Console access so I can check the usage of my credentials.

Doe someone know if this API is available and how it works (if it's available)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one API that gives you access to data in Google Developers console its called [Google Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/) .  Unfortunately for us it is extremely limited in what it can do.

- Get a list of all projects associated with an account.
- Create new projects.
- Update existing projects.
- Delete projects.
- Undelete, or recover, projects that you don’t want to delete.

Last I checked it does not give you access to check your credentials or quota usage.  sadly

My blog post about it when it was released: [Google Developer console API](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-api/)

Comment: I'm looking forward to a completer version of this API . Do you know anything about the current development plans @DaImTo?

Comment: What I know is a whole lot of nothing.  There hasn't been a word about it.  Why they made it in the first place and left it so well lacking I don't know.